# Detect if method is called in background / foreground

Tags: ios, background, nsthread

I would like to detect if a method in objective c is called and executing on `NSThread` that is running on foreground or background.

Thanks

Comment: Place a breakpoint inside said method, then when the app pauses on that method you will be able to see which thread it is being run on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether the current thread is the main one with:

```
+ (BOOL)[NSThread isMainThread]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //this thread called method in background thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                                 (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
            [self callBackMethod];
        });

        //this method call work with main thread
        [self callBackMethod];
    }
    -(void)callBackMethod
    {
        if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
            NSLog(@"main thread....");
        }else
        {
            NSLog(@"background thread..");
        }
    }
```

Comment: By using this callbackmethod you can easily know, method calling is from background thread or mainthread.